# Не пропадает модальное окно при голосовании за переоткрытие

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, переоткрытие-вопросов

Если в очереди на переоткрытие проголосовать за переоткрытие, то открывается модальное окно, где предлагается выбрать 2 варианта: **Да** и **Отмена**

Если нажать **Да**, то оно не пропадает, хотя очередь продвигается. Если нажать еще раз **Да**, то вылетает ошибка, "Вы уже голосовали за переоткрытие".

Comment: Тоже самое. Надо бы на MSE зарепортить, если там ещё никто этого не сделал.